# How to teleport all players from a specific world into another world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bukkit

I have a Paper-Server (1.16.4) with MultiversePlugin (and some other plugins, like EssentialsX) and multiple worlds.
Is there a command which can teleport all players of a specific world into another world?

something like (only example!):`/teleport @allPlayers:World2 to world:World3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be possible using the [/execute](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute) command.

```
/execute in <toDimension> run tp @a[nbt={Dimension:"<fromDimension>"}] <location>
```

Comment: That command does not really work. `<fromDimension>` must be a Dimension (like overworld,nether,..) whereas `<toDimension>` can point to a world. This worked partially: `execute in overworld run execute in newspawn run tp @a 0 64 0` but it has same effect as `execute in newspawn run tp @a 0 64 0`  The problem is, ALL players from all worlds are teleported to the new world (newspawn).

Comment: I could have tought of that @a realy means all and not all in the current dimension, anyways I will try to find another way, if I can't I will delete this "answer"

Comment: @Ben Updated the answer. The player has a `Dimension` nbt tag which can be used to select players in a specific dimension.

Comment: @NoelNemeth Does the `Dimension` NBT tag work with players in other multiverse worlds with the Multiverse plugin?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Honestly, I didn't tested it, but I think it must register the world somewhere and it would be the most logical way to follow the "standard".

Comment: Just tested it, works fine. Multiverse worlds are also prefixed with `minecraft:`

Comment: Still doesn't work. **No Entity was found** Isn't NBT-Tag Dimension just for Overworld, Nether or the End? I tried: `/execute in newspawn run tp @a[nbt={Dimension:"FlatWorld"}] 0 64 0` whereas newspawn is my destination world and FlatWorld my source world.

Comment: @Ben You need to prefix world names with `minecraft:`, so `FlatWorld` becomes `minecraft:FlatWorld`

Comment: Works, thank you! Fully working command: `/execute in newspawn run tp @a[nbt={Dimension:"minecraft:flatworld"}] 0 64 0`